# How to generate all possible 3-chars strings in c#?

Tags: c#, string

The question is :

> How to generate a list of all possible 3-chars strings in C#?

To clairify, that's within the domain of 64<sub>10</sub> and 90<sub>10</sub>

Comment: What is the domain from which characters are drawn?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> GetAllStrings(params char[] inputCharacterSet) {
    return from n in inputCharacterSet
           from m in inputCharacterSet
           from k in inputCharacterSet
           select new string(new [] { n, m, k });
}
```

Comment: Much more elegant that what I would have wrote (3 for loops, spitting out strings to stdout :D)

Comment: This is correct, so I'll toss in a point, but I think it might be clearer as nested for loops.

Comment: @Mark: LINQ is certainly fancier, but given that this looks like a homework question, I'm concerned that it might be overkill.

Comment: Steven: LINQ is rarely suitable for doing homework... and that's why it's perfectly suited for answering them ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
public IEnumerable<String> Get3CharStrings(char[] domain)
{
    foreach(char a in domain)
     foreach(char b in domain)
      foreach(char c in domain)
       yield return "" + a + b + c;
}
```

**EDIT:** This is actually quite a bit slower than the LINQ solution posted by Mehrdad, although most of the difference lies in the use of `return "" + a + b + c` instead of `return new string(new[] { a, b, c})`.

Actual statistics (26-character alphabet, 10k iterations:

Mehrdad's code: 72.983 seconds
My code: 127.205 seconds
My code with Mehrdad's return statement: 75.055 seconds

Comment: This is less elegant than the LINQ, and the way the letters are concatenated is particularly ugly.

Comment: Eh: it's readable, and I'd expect the jit-optimizer to fix the normal problems with string concatentation here.

Comment: I liked the Linq solution, but actually this one is easier to read, which makes it better

Comment: If the concatenation were better, I'd say it was about the same.